# Excel vba code cleanup

Tags: vba, excel

The code below works but isn't fast and I'm sure there are ways it could simplified. I'm not a coder -- I just compiled a few samples that I found.  I really don't understand the range/end/offset pieces for the pasting aspect.  Here's what I'm trying to do:
1. Print the first three worksheets in the workbook
2. Create three new worksheets at the end of the workbook
3. copy and paste values, formats, and column widths to the three new worksheets from the first three.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub Print_copy_Current_Workbook()
'Prints the current active workbook in Excel

Sheets("Draw").PrintOut
Sheets("Calculations").PrintOut
Sheets("AIN").PrintOut

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Tabs As Variant
    Dim I As Byte
    Tabs = Array("Draw Final", "AIN Final", "Calculations Final")
    For I = LBound(Tabs) To UBound(Tabs)
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1).Name = Tabs(I)
            Next I
Sheets("Draw").Range("A1:L1000").Copy
With Sheets("Draw Final").Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
End With
Sheets("AIN").Range("A1:L1000").Copy
With Sheets("AIN Final").Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
End With
Sheets("Calculations").Range("A1:L1000").Copy
With Sheets("Calculations Final").Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: possible candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) assuming the code works as OP says it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion below.

Also I would avoid `Option Base 1` - it's rarely used, and will just cause problems later when you get used to working with zero-based arrays.

```
Sub Print_copy_Current_Workbook()
    Dim Tabs As Variant
    Dim I As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Tabs = Array("Draw", "AIN", "Calculations")

    For I = LBound(Tabs) To UBound(Tabs)

        Sheets(Tabs(I)).PrintOut
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Tabs(I) & " Final"
        CopyPaste Sheets(Tabs(I)).Range("A1:L1000")

    Next I

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub CopyPaste(rng As Range)
    rng.Copy
    'this is a new sheet we're pasting to, so why not just Range("A1") ?
    With Sheets(rng.Parent.Name & " Final").Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With

End Sub
```